# Photoshop merging timeline frames in 1 image side by side

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation

I have created an animation in Photoshop. I want to merge them in 1 image file side by side. Is there an easy way to do it? Because I will do this process about 10-15 times.

My animation timeline (click for full resolution)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6GJz.png]

I want a result like this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7SEI.png]

Edit:
I tried a technic but couldn't be successful.

- I made layers from frames

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwOkT.png]

- I changed canvas of the image

[image: http://i.imgur.com/fvoeoik.png]

- I made all layers visible and selected all layers

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UinJY.png]

- I pressed Layer>Align>Left Edge

[image: http://i.imgur.com/zDYkX5L.png]

- Result:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/3EGc6FE.png]

Why can't I get the correct result?

Answer (score 1):

When you click "Flatten frames into layers", photoshop fill create each frame on a seperate layer. Set your canvas' width and height to dimensions you want and create a new layer below the current one and fill its inside.

By this, you can protect the original weight which can be lose because of transparency.

Let's write like this (for example)

· Your canvas 100x100px
· Your layer is 90x90px (so you can lose 5px each side if you don't create a filled layer below)
[image: You should get something like this]

· Count your layers (e.g 10)
· Your canvas should be 1000px
· Copy both layers (background fill and your original layer together) to the right until you get something like below:

[image]

· Remove all the background fill layers.
· Save the imag

Comment: I tried something but couldn't get the correct result. Can you look at them?

Comment: Because you align all objects to left. You need to order them manually